# Thymeleaf not replacing variable for XML template

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is the first time I'm using Thymeleaf, I want to replace variables in an XML template and return the content as a String. I am able to load the template, but Thymeleaf does not replace variables.
Here is an example of a variable:
`<arc:set attr="CountryCode" value="${argument}"/>"`

And here is the Java part:

```
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext());
        resolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".xml");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.XML);

        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);

        Context ctx = new Context();
        ctx.setVariable("argument", "fr");
        String xml = engine.process("Checker", ctx);
```

The variable is not replaced if I print the content of "xml". I tried to surround the variable with [[]] but it did not work.
Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you add `th:` to the `value` attribute: `th:value="${argument}"`? Also, does your template have that extra `"` at the end, after the final `>`, as shown in the question, or is that just a copy/paste issue?

Comment: See also the note in [this section](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#a-multi-language-welcome) of the guide about adding a namespace to your template: `xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"` - which "_works as an incantation_".

Comment: @andrewjames The "th:" did the trick! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

works for me when I change the template mode to TEXT

```
resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
```